# Python Recursive addition

Tags: python, recursion

Recursive Multiplication
Design a recursive function that accepts two arguments into the parameters x and
y. The function should return the value of x times y. Remember, multiplication can
be performed as repeated addition as follows:
7 × 4 = 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4

Yes, this is my home work from like three weeks ago, but i just cant figure this thing out.

```
def mult(x, y):

     x = int(input("enter x"))
     y = int(input("enter y"))
     i = 0
     for i in range(y):
             x = x + (x - 1)
             i = i + 1
             print(x)
 mult(x, y)
```

This is what i have, but if i put 10 for x and 10 for y i get 1024 instead of 100. what is going on here?

Comment: Your method isn't recursive

Comment: Not sure how you get 1024; your posted code would produce 9217 for x = 10 and y = 10.. It'll print out another 9 numbers before that point, but none of those is ever equal to 1024 either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incrementing `x` each time you add `x - 1` to it. So for 10 times 10 you start with `10`, then add `10 - 1 = 9`, making `19`, and *store that back in `x`*. The next iteration you add `19 - 1 = 18` to `x = 19`, so now you have `x = 37`. Then you add `37 - 1 = 36` to `37`, so now you have `x = 73`. Next you'd add `72`, and you are already way past the real answer of 100, in just 4 steps; there are another 6 to go!

Keep your sum in a *separate* variable, and start that at zero. Add `y` to that each time:

```
total = 0
for i in range(x):
    total = total + y

print(total)
```

There is no need to subtract 1 from `x`, the `for` loop takes care of counting for you.

None of this is actually using *recursion*. This is a recursive version:

```
def mult(x, y):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    return y + mult(x - 1, y)
```

So if `x` is 0, there is no multiplication and you return 0, otherwise you sum `y` to the multiplication of `y` and `x - 1`. Yes, *here* you *do* subtract one.

Comment: x = 0
y = 0
def mult(x, y):
    x = int(input("enter x"))
    y = int(input("enter y"))
    total = mult(x, 1)
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    return y + mult(x - 1, y)
    print(total)        
mult(x, y)

Comment: @RichardBermudezKenjaTrading move the `input()` calls *out* of the function. You don't want to ask for new values each recursive call. So instead of `x = 0`, use `x = int(input('Enter x: ')`, same for `y`, *then* call the `mult(x, y)` function.

Comment: x = int(input("enter x"))
y = int(input("enter y"))
def mult(x, y):

   
    total = mult(x, 1)
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    return y + mult(x - 1, y)

print(mult(x,y))


mult(x, y)

Comment: it goes in to an infinite loop and then says its reached its maximum recursion

Comment: @RichardBermudezKenjaTrading your version does not match mine, does it. You call `mult()` on the first line of the function, passing in `x` and 1. That'll only lead to the function forever calling itself. Why did you add that call?

Comment: I took that out. My first 2 lines are the x and y input. Then call to mult(x,y)

Comment: @RichardBermudezKenjaTrading excellent. Do you understand a bit why this works now?

Comment: I wish. I really really wish. Ive watches videos, read all the questions. But recursion fails me. I chose the easiest excersize. It was supposed to be x plus x ran y times. But i dont understand how recursion breaks it down or makes it easier.

Comment: @RichardBermudezKenjaTrading: Perhaps try and step through the code with the [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/); step through [4 times 2](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def+mult%28x,+y%29%3A%0A++++if+x+%3D%3D+0%3A%0A++++++++return+0%0A++++return+y+%2B+mult%28x+-+1,+y%29%0A%0Amult%284,+2%29&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=true&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=0) for example.

Answer (score 1):

The recursion is:

```
  mult(x, y) = x + mult(x, y-1)
  mult(x, 1) = x  // This is the base condition
```

Now, you should be able to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code, I normally use C++ 
print "welcome to recursive function"
x = input("Enter the x: " )
y = input("Enter the y: " )

CONSTANT = x
def recursive(x, y):
        if y == 0:
            x = 0
            return x
        if y == 1:
            return x
        if y > 1:
            x = x + recursive(x, y-1)
            return x
x = recursive(x, y)
print "The resulting value is ", x

1. List item